# PassportJS just hangs after creating a user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

After I signup a user using passport the screen just hangs and it does not redirect me to the screen set in successRedirect:

model/user.js

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataType){

  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataType.STRING,
    localPassword: DataType.STRING,
    lastName: DataType.STRING,
    localEmail: DataType.STRING,
    cellNumber: DataType.INTEGER
  },
      {
        instanceMethods: {
          validPassword: function(password){
              return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
          }
        }
      }
  );
    return User;
};
```

routes/index.js

```
router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect : '/',
  failureRedirect : '/err',
  failureFlash : true
}));
```

config/passportConfig.js

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    model.User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(null, user);
    });
});


passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        model.User.findOne({
            where: {
                localEmail: email
            }
        }).then(function(existingUser) {
                if (existingUser) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
                }
                else {
                    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);
                    var newUser = model.User.build({name: req.body.name, lastName: req.body.lastName, localEmail: req.body.email, cellNumber: req.body.cellNumber, localPassword: hash});
                    newUser.save().then(function(){
                        done(null, newUser);
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', err))
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage',e.name + " " + e.message));
            })
    }));
```

so basically what happens is it creates the entry in the database and the it stays on the register screen and loads. It says waiting for localhost, but goes on forever. I am new to passport and sequelize, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note to your bcrypt part: You should seed the password and there's an easy performance improvement by switching from the synchronous hashing function (`hashSync(data, salt)`) to the asynchronous version. (`hash(data, salt, callback)`) (Since the asynchronous version won't halt execution). What you're doing now is using `8` as salt, which is weak and non random. (You probably wanted to use `8` as input for `genSalt`)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem lies in this code block:

```
newUser.save().then(function(){
   done(null, newUser);
})
```

Since you are calling `done` but not returning it, Bluebird (the promise lib that sequelize uses) sees that promise as returning `undefined`. Therefor it runs the rest of the code in parallel without waiting for it to resolve.

Try adding a return to the statement:

```
newUser.save().then(function(){
    return done(null, newUser);
})
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I did try this. But it still seems to be stuck. the page just keeps on loading and it says: waiting for localhost....

Comment: Hi @AndreCoetzee I am having the same issue as you where and was wondering how you solved this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715236/passport-js-successredirect-hangs-nodejs any pointers appreciated, thank you